# Writing xml with dataset to xml how to read it back

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database, dataset

I have written a simple program that writes a data set from the database out to a xml file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        {
            string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\names.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");

            using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
            {
                string strSql = "Select * from Table1"; //only launch in main
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " Querying Launch Parameters";


                try
                {

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\temp\\names.mdb; Persist Security Info = False");
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "fname,sname");
                    // Extract data set to XML file 
                    ds.WriteXml(@"c:\\temp\\my.xml");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Error " + ex + "\n"; ;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

How ever writing code for the reverse process is drawing up blank datasets

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSql = "insert into Tabel1";

        try
        {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\temp\\Set.mdb; Persist Security Info = False");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("c:\\temp\\my.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml("c:\\temp\\my.xml");

            // while (ds.ReadXml("c:\\temp\\my.xml"));
            {
                ds.ReadXml("c:\\temp\\my.xml");
            }


            // dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            // dataGridView1.DataMember = "launch";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Error " + ex + "\n";
        }
        finally
        {
            //fsReadXml.Close();
        }
    }
```

how to fix it so that I get a complete dataset back??

Comment: Add schema :              ds.WriteXml(@"c:\\temp\\my.xml",XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: what happen if you only use `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml("c:\\temp\\my.xml");`

Comment: @Damith all I know is when displaying it witht he line  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; I dont get my data simple though it is displayied

Comment: @jdweng that adds the schema only to the file it does not seam to create the data. Is there a way of combining the two??

Comment: Should be : ds.SchemaSerializationMode = SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704963/how-nto-read-a-database-table-to-xml-but-no-joy-insterting-it-back-c-sharp-msacc.  Instead of posting multiple questions for essentially the same problem, edit your original question with improved detail and formatting.

Comment: @Data See my comments on your other question.  Your code has multiple issues that nobody here has addressed.  These answers fail to recognize that your code represents an overall misunderstanding of the Dataset schema and the data objects you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to read the XML file:

```
  XmlReader xmlFile;
  xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("c:\\temp\\my.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
int i = 0;
string str = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\my.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
```

refer this link http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ds.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\my.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

and

```
ds.ReadXml(@"c:\temp\my.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

note that when you write your dataset you have @ and escaping \

```
ds.WriteXml(@"c:\\temp\\my.xml");
```